# log4j custom logger method not getting called

Tags: java, log4j

I want to override `error(Object message, Throwable t)` of `log4j.Logger` class to change few things.
however when I extend MYLogger extends Logger, it still does not call my implementation of error(..) method rather super class's method is getting called.

here's code

```
public class MYLogger extends Logger {

    private static final String FQCN = MYLogger.class.getName();


    protected MYLogger(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


public void error(Object message, Throwable t,final String codeKey, final String messageKey) {
        System.out.println("codeKey "+codeKey+" messageKey"+messageKey);
        String fmessage=codeKey+":"+messageKey;

        if (this.repository.isDisabled(40000))
            return;
        if (Level.ERROR.isGreaterOrEqual(getEffectiveLevel()))
            forcedLog(FQCN, Level.ERROR, fmessage, null);
    }

}
```

And test class from where I'm trying to call my implementation of error(..)

```
public class TestLogger {

    protected static final MYLogger LOG = (MYLogger) MYLogger.getLogger(TestLogger.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.error("Testing log error");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that the runtime type returned by `getLogger` is `MYLogger` ?

Comment: that line/statement is resulting in below exceptionException in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be cast to test.MYLogger 
 at test.TestLogger.<clinit>(TestLogger.java:9)

Comment: That's it. `getLogger` gives you a `Logger` not `MYLogger`. Not sure about how to resolve this. I bet there must be some tutorial on custom Loggers in log4j.

Comment: did not find anything on this, please let us know if you have some pointer

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://www.jajakarta.org/log4j/jakarta-log4j-1.1.3/docs/deepExtension.html By the way: which version of log4j are we talking about? log4j or log4j2 ? In latter case you can read this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

Comment: Hey there, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem once and I've fixed this way:

```
public class MYLogger {

    private Logger  logger;

    public MYLogger(String name) throws IOException {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(name);                
    }

    public void error(String message){
        if (logger != null) 
            logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is basically wrapping Logger, which can be done but that means I need to either ask developer to get instance of MyLogger for error logging and Logger for debug which is not good idea or I need to copy all the methods from Logger to MyLogger.